# How can I render a next.js page inside my react.js app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js, server-side-rendering

As part of optimizations of my e-commerce app, I want to improve the performance score in [Pagespeed](https://pagespeed.web.dev/).
My idea is that I can render the hero component of my React.js application with Next.js (serve it with ready data from server), that way the page will loads initially with all the necessary elements.

The expected result is to enter the app than request the hero component and then I will have it in one file all ready without any loading time.

The general idea looks like that:

```
// My React.js app (app.js file):
const App = () => {
 ...

 return (
    <Hero /> // <----- My hero page from my react.js app but served with next.js

    ... // another pages from my regular react.js application
 )
}
```

**My questions is:**

1. This is good idea in order to make my application load faster?
2. there is something that can lead to troubles combining both of those technologies together?
3. How can I configure them to work together? (I'm working with webpack without `create-react-app`). I want to serve the app exactly like today with single entry point and single script (`webpack serve ......`)

**Additional information:**
versions:

```
"typescript": "4.7.4",
"webpack": "5.73.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
```

Comment: Hmmh. I don't grok NextJS, but based on a feeling I'm getting, have you followed Rule 2 of the Optimization Club: `The second rule of Optimization Club is, you do not Optimize without measuring.` -- are you sure that loading and processing this data is really relevant for slowing down your app?